# Alpha blending with the same transparent image

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-core

I'd like to draw in my iPad app as in the following image. [image]

But what I got is the following result. [image]

Following is my code to draw the image.

```
 [brushImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:.1f];
```

How do I blend a transparent image and get the result like first picture? Any suggestion?

Many thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you need to setup a clip region to exclude the parts you've already drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a non transparent image for the different parts and apply the alpha to a containing view. That way, instead of getting this:
[image]

You'll get this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

i guess, when you start brushing you should create a UIView, that will contain all the points;
than apply the alpha to that view

(this is a useful way, because let you easily implement the undo functionality in your project)